# Capture all occurences of substring after specific text regex python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a long document in which the line of my interest starts with `Categories :` . I want to find all words separated by `,` after `Categories :` .
Here's an example line

```
Categories : Turbo Prop , Very Light , Light , Mid Size
```

I want to find `start index` and `end index` of `Turbo Prop`, `Very Light`, `Light`, `Mid Size`

I am using following code

```
regex_pattern = r"(?<=Categories : )([A-Za-z ]+(?:,)?)+"

matched_text = regex.search(regex_pattern,doc_tex)
```

But `matched_text.groups()` is only giving  `Mid Size`. In short, I want to find all occurences of `group 1` after `Categories`.

Comment: Sorry, someone flagged the comment with suggested solution and mods removed it. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in two steps. First split the line using `:`, then split the second part using `,`.

```
category_string = line.split(':')[1]
categories = category_string.split(',')
```

Comment: My goal is to find `start index` and `end index` of tokens. That's why I am using capturing goup where I can simply get these indices using `span` method.
Finding start and end index of each category text would be longer. Also these categories might occur other than category string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the comments answered the OP's question, but for completeness I thought I'd post the answer they discuss. It looks like Python's re module does not store all all instances of a repeated capture group; see [issue 7132](https://bugs.python.org/issue7132). The [regex](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/) package, however, adds additional methods to handle repeated capture groups, including.

- captures -Returns a list of the strings matched in a group or groups.
- starts - Returns a list of the start positions.
- ends - Returns a list of the end positions.
- spans - Returns a list of the spans. Compare with matchobject.span([group]).

Hence, using the regex package with the `matchedobject.starts` and `matchedobject.ends` methods should work.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you can get all captures per group, together with their start and end indices, using

```py
import regex
text = "Categories : Turbo Prop , Very Light , Light , Mid Size"
regex_pattern = r"Categories\s*:(?:\s*([A-Za-z ]+)\b(?:\s*,)?)+"
m = regex.search(regex_pattern, text)
result = list(zip(m.captures(1),m.starts(1),m.ends(1)))
print(result) 
# => [('Turbo Prop', 13, 23), ('Very Light', 26, 36), ('Light', 39, 44), ('Mid Size', 47, 55)]
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##VY5LC8IwEITv/RVLT4nWgngriIhXBUHx4AOJdmkDtgmbLbT98zXxAXqa2V3m27Edl6aeDYOurCEGwgLbiLFlmEO8UoyFIY0OMtg3dDOwJWMhgQNSB2tdlOyHr250DjvdYxy9MFermJFqT6If1NmNMrHIvIjTcnJUkx4uY3m@vXeJXMhxHFUhFCCpQ0X3UvwREwgNpX/jmkdo@tCORa@tqNK7stz4g5jKpEodK@KPxzoPTsrIkq5ZvNNyGJ4)

More details from PyPi `regex` documentation:

> A match object has additional methods which return information on all
> the successful matches of a repeated capture group. These methods are:
>
> - `matchobject.captures([group1, ...])`
>
>   - Returns a list of the strings
>     matched in a group or groups. Compare with `matchobject.group([group1, ...])`.
> - `matchobject.starts([group])`
>
>   - Returns a list of the start
>     positions. Compare with `matchobject.start([group])`.
> - `matchobject.ends([group])`
>
>   - Returns a list of the end positions. Compare
>     with `matchobject.end([group])`.
> - `matchobject.spans([group])`
>
>   - Returns a
>     list of the spans. Compare with `matchobject.span([group])`.

Note I had to revamp your regex a bit:

- `Categories\s*:` - matches  `Categories`, zero or more whitespaces, `:`
- `(?:\s*([A-Za-z ]+)\b(?:\s*,)?)+` - one or more repetitions of

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
  - `([A-Za-z ]+)` - one or more ASCII letters or spaces
  - `\b` - a word boundary (so, Group 1 value will end with a letter)
  - `(?:\s*,)?` - an optional sequence of zero or more whitespace chars and a comma.